# Can ions / protons / charge liquids generate magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, ions

can ions moving in a solution generate magnetic field if yes then why is it not more commonly used. lithium ion's in batteries pass from cathode to anode separated by a membrane to discharge the current. does this movement generate a significant magnetic field.

Comment: Any moving charges may create a net current that would generate magnetic fields.

Answer (score 0):

The most fundamental source of magnetic field is any charged particle moving with uniform speed. In order to have a magnetic field of measurable/ discoverable magnitude, it is necessary to have a considerably large amount of charge moving with greater speed. To understand this point you can go through the formula for magnetic field produced by a solenoid. Because of an extremely small magnitude of magnetic permeability of air or vacuum, in order to produce a substantial magnetic field, you will need a greater amount of current flow. That is, a large magnitude of charge should flow (remember that one ampere of current is equals to 1 coulomb of charge flowing in one second. Further, one coulomb of charge constitutes how many electrons? This gives you a rough idea about the number of charged particles and the magnitude of charge that should flow, to produce a sizable magnetic field)
Even then, it will still be difficult to measure or experience such kind of magnetic field, again, because of its smaller magnitude.